# Magento 2 How to add Magnifier to product list page?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, product-images, product-list

I have enabled Magnifier to product detail page from theme `etc/view.xml`

```
<var name="magnifier">
    <var name="fullscreenzoom">20</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
    <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
    <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
    <var name="width"></var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
    <var name="height"></var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
    <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
    <var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
</var>
```

I have updated enabled `false` to `true` and its working on product detail page.

But how can we add or enable Magnifier to product list page?

Comment: Hi nikuj use product quick view instead of displaying zoom on product list page. :)

Comment: thanks for a reply but @Nits magnifier is a requirement.

Comment: you should try with external magnifier jQuery plugin for list page

Comment: @AasimGoriya good suggestion but, it is last option. Magento provide Magnifier widget so it is first prio for now.

Comment: @NikunjVadariya, Did you get any solution for this?